# jQuery search table for a row with multiple specific values in specific columns

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a specific row in a table, where the td value in the first column is the_month and the td value in the second column is the_year.

```
var the_month = 3,
    the_year = 15;
var tableRow = jQuery("td").filter(function() {
            return jQuery(this).text() == the_month;
        }).siblings().filter(function() {
            return jQuery(this).text() == the_year;
        }).parent('tr')
```

This code is almost what I want, but it's looking at every td.  How can I limit this to only look for the_month in column 1 and the_year in column 2.

Edit: I understand the lack of clarity now.  I have a huge table. I'm trying to find the row where the value of the first column is equal to the variable I created, called the_month, which is a number, and the value of the second column is the_year, which is also a variable I created.  These variables are numbers.  The code I originally posted keeps finding the value of the_month, let's say the_month = 3, in other columns of the wrong row.  So I want to look for a row that has the number 3 in the first column and the number 15 in the second column.

Comment: *How can I limit this to only look in the correct columns?* is a bit unclear. I mean everything is unclear. What means "correct"? what columns? what rows? what? :)

Comment: Which columns are the "correct" columns? Can you post the table HTML?

Comment: "I want to find the row where the td value in the 1st column is the_month and the td value in the 2nd column is the_year." I'm not sure how much more specific I can get.  The HTML is really long, there's 16 columns, and dozens of rows, which is why I didn't post it (also contains some sensitive data).

Comment: are you open to using different js libraries for this or do you want a modification in this code itself?

Comment: It seems like you should put your second query inside of your first.  Basically, find the month in the first td, then if that month matches, find the year.  Does this sound like what you're wanting to do?

Comment: @Pratik The end goal is to change other td values in the row that matches the results of this search. That I can do, I just need to find the right row. I can't add any dependencies.

Comment: Could you please mark one of the answers as correct if it helped you or post the existing problems

Comment: The issue with the answers provided is the use of .eq().  This returns the index of the array returned by jQuery, and doesn't actually limit the search to a particular row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code works as it stands, and I'm understanding you correctly, instead of making your query search for month **and** year, you should make it search for month **then** year

I haven't used filters, but I've made what you're looking for (I think) in [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/32n4geee/)

Here's the accompanying code:

```
$('tr').each(function(i){
    var month = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
    if(month == 'the_month'){
        var year = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();  
        if(year == 'the_year'){
            var tableRow = i;
            console.log(i);  
        }
    }
});
```

Now, since you didn't have any html posted, I can only assume what I've written is what you meant.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32n4geee/2/

This fiddle has the table code, and a few tweaks.  Finds nothing.

Comment: @AnthonyRoberts Actually, it works perfectly.  check the console - it found row 2 to be the row you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, it but it's logging the row number.  What would the actual row be?  I want it to return the row, not a number.

Comment: ok, add a second var to the each function called row, and then set tableRow = row, and this is correct.  If you update, I'll mark it correct. Also, I'm going to delete the table code in the fiddle, so you might want to remove the link to it.

Comment: @AnthonyRoberts, I'm sorry, I don't understand how you mean "the actual row".  Row 2 is the actual row.  If you want the actual row minus the table headers, it would be row-2, bring it to row 0.  Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: yeah, I wasn't thinking clearly.  I ended up using this to get what I needed, which is a jQuery object that I can use to update the other fields in the row.

jQuery('.tablesorter tbody tr').eq(i)

Comment: Edit: i has to be out of the quote.

jQuery('.tablesorter tbody tr:eq('+ i +')')

Comment: @AnthonyRoberts, I'm glad I could help!  That's strange, I thought `.eq(i)` would work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This would have your first and second td's filtered out. http://jsfiddle.net/66za2f8n/2/

```
//you can modify the select to be #idofTable tr
    var tableRow = $("table tr").filter(function() {

                return $(this).find("td").eq(0).text() == "the_month" &&
                    $(this).find("td").eq(1).text() == "the_year";
            });


    console.log(tableRow);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't return what I need. the .eq(1) only finds the first td, it doesn't look at the entire table. .eq() returns the index, which is 0 based, btw.

Comment: Sorry, still not working for me.  I'll post the issue as soon as I've done some more testing

Comment: I didn't mean to imply by the lack of response that it didn't.  I ended up marking @ntgCleaner's answer as correct because I used it.  We bounced back and forth on some confusion caused by my imprecise descriptions on the problem, and when I got things working, I just marked his as the answer.  And personal time and a long weekend to the non-response MO.  I do appreciate the help.